# Specifying a scale value with img src

Tags: html

Is it possible to scale the image in an img src declaraton?  Something like:

```
<a href="clown.jpg" ><img src="clown.jpg width=25%"" </a>
```

Here you'd click the 1/4 size clown and see a full size clown.

Thanks

Comment: Please make more clear what you're asking. Also tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: everything is possible. please be more specific about that problem which you have encountered and need help with.

Comment: 'Sorry.  The link line didn't print the first time in the question.
I don't want to just try things because even if something worked  there could be a good reason for never doing it, or a much better way..

Comment: The original sample markup above is neither valid or complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it works just as you specified, but you need the quotes around `25%`, not after them.
Also, you're missing a close angle bracket for `img`.

```
<a href="clown.jpg"><img src="clown.jpg width="25%"/></a>
```

It displays a quarter-size image (scaled proportionally in both dimensions) that, when clicked, points to the full-size image.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/kE6MY/)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use CSS:

```
<a href="clown.jpg"><img src="clown.jpg" style="width:25%" /></a>
```

This would display the clown.jpg image at 25% of it's normal width (with the height scaled proportionally), and when the image is clicked, it would link to the full-size version.